# How do I get the URL path after a redirect -- with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

This could be a little off the ballpark, but a friend asked me about it and it's kind of bothering me. How do you figure out the current path in your address bar if the server redirects all requests to a default file, say, index.html.

Let's say you entered:

```
www.example.com/
```

And your server configuration automatically redirects this request to

```
www.example.com/index.html
```

But the address in your url bar does not change! So how do you figure out using Javascript that the path on this url is index.html?

I looked into location.pathname but that's only giving me /.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that it's not actually a redirect.  When you type `'www.example.com'` into your web browser, the browser generates an HTTP request like the following:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.16.3 (i686-pc-cygwin) libcurl/7.16.3 OpenSSL/
0.9.8h zlib/1.2.3 libssh2/0.15-CVS
Host: www.example.com
Accept: */*
```

Note that it's requesting a document named literally `/`.  There are two possible responses by the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
(more headers)

Content...
```

And

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: (location of redirect)
(more headers)

(Optional content)
```

In Case #2, you can get the redirect location since it's actually a redirect.  But in Case #1, the *server* is doing the redirection: it sees a request for `/` and instead serves up the content for whatever its index page is (e.g. `index.html`, `index.php`, `default.aspx`, etc.).  As far as your browser is concerned, that's just the content for the document `/`.  It doesn't know it's been redirected.

Answer (score 4):

If the redirect happens on the server then the browser is not aware of it and you cannot access the actual resource in javascript. For example, a servlet might "forward" to another resource on the server.

If the server sends a redirect command to the browser and the browser requests the new url then the browser does know about it and you can get it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this, except somehow embedding the webserver's filename into the document. As far as the browser is concerned, there is no `index.html`, the page is just `/`.